# Efficiency of Select query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, filter, sqlanywhere

Consider two queries,

1. Select * from table where size = 'L';
2. Select * from table where id IN (691,12,123,5123,....); # id is primary key for the table. and covers all the cases for which size ='L'.

Now consider a table which has 2 million records and i'll be firing both the queries.

Which of the two queries will run faster and why?

Consider this situation in terms of a system which filters out data on select of the option.

Comment: Is `size` a column? If so, is there an index on `size`?

Comment: presumably, roughly 20 to 25% of the rows are size 'L'? That's one big IN()!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Short: Ths answer depends on how many rows have `size='L'`. If there are many rows the the second will be more efficient because an index on `size` ist slow (cardinality).

Comment: Hi benni, Count of both the queries remains the same. now which one is more efficient.

Comment: Do a `Select Count(*) as lCount from table where size = 'L'` and compare the result with a `Select Count(*) as allCount from table`. If lCount is very small compared to allCount you will see no difference. If lCount is big compared to allCount the 2nd quer (Primary-key) will be faster.

Comment: can you explain why?